# Is there an intuitive way to understand $Pair(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} + x$?

Tags: logic, pattern-recognition

After a lot of effort I discovered some pattern that the function:

$$Pair(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} + x$$

essentially zigzags along the grid with $\mathbf N$ vs $\mathbf N$ (natural numbers). So intuitively, given any P(x,y) we follow the grid path. However, this seems like a very hacky way to understand it. How could someone have come up with this? Where did it come from? It looks nothing at all random and it has very interesting properties like:

1. its bijective
2. its computable (easy to prove)
3. if $Pair(x,y) =a $ then $Right(a) = x \leq a$ and $Left(a) = y < a$.

number 1 and 3 seem especially especial (and I wonder why they are true). But is this property of zigzagging obvious just by looking at the equation? (as well as the other properties)? Should this zigzaging be obvious without brute forcing the computaiton of 100 of these numbers? I am assuming their is some sort of pattern to this function but I can't see it...

---

context: comes up in development of Godel numbering: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf

page 85.

Comment: I thought the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) was a pretty good explanation. Atleast for thinking processes of the derivation.

Comment: @Mason oh wow. Thats what happens when a set of notes introduces a well known concept but doesn't acknowledge it or put it in context with the rest of mathematical facts. Argh dum notes. Thanks Mason Though.

Comment: @Mason fixed it. I meant $Left(a) =  x$ while $Right(a) = y$ s.t. $Pair(x,y) = a$ so $Pair(Left(a),Right(a)) = a $

Comment: Yeah. I found the wiki when I was doing my own exploration of pairing functions 3 or 4 months ago. Maybe you'll enjoy these musings I made while I was exploring. The [pairing function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wlo3nrojxb) and the so-called [elegant pairing function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t6nirc7gza)

Comment: Raymond Smullyan's "Recursion theory for metamathematics" contains a very nice explanation of this pairing function (page 33).

Answer (score 4):

Zigzagging is kind of obvious if you look at it in the right way. Pair of $x$ and $y$ is equal to the $(x+y)$th triangle number, plus $x$. The $y$ term is guaranteeing that the "plus $x$" term on the end will not cause the traversal to run more than the full length of the hypotenuse. So $y$ is effectively telling you how tall the triangle is (in the sense of distance from the origin along the line $y=x$ to the hypotenuse), and $x$ is telling you where along the hypotenuse you're located.

Comment: +1: That's a nice explanation of how to understand the formula. I expect the formula was found by drawing the zig-zag pattern thought of as a map from $\Bbb{N}$ onto $\Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}$ and then figuring out the inverse mapping (which you'd expect to be a fairly simple polynomial given knowledge of triangular numbers etc.).

Comment: what is the (x+y)th triangle number?

Comment: @RobArthan It's actually really annoyingly difficult to show that it's bijective - I'm doing that in Agda at the moment, and it's a massive pain.

Comment: @Pinocchio The $n$th triangle number is defined as $\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)$, and it's the number of points in the triangle you get when you cut an $n \times n$ square of equally spaced points in half along a diagonal.

Comment: $T_n $ is also the sum $1+2+\dots + n$. See here for more on [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: @PatrickStevens: "annoyingly difficult" is often the way with formal machine-checked proofs. Presumably you need to define the inverse function recursively and then prove it's the inverse. Good luck!

Comment: what do you mean by "The y term is guaranteeing that the "plus x " term on the end will not cause the traversal to run more than the full length of the hypotenuse."?

Comment: how did you figure out that the height to the y=x line was y? Your explanation seems to be true but it came out of nowhere to me. Perhaps now that I see what triangle function is just some of the first n numbers I see where that piece of it came from.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like this:

$$\begin{array} {ccccr}
(0, 0)_{\color{red}0} \\
(1, 0)_{\color{red}1} & (0, 1)_{\color{red}2} & \\
(2, 0)_{\color{red}3} & (1, 1)_{\color{red}4} & (0, 2)_{\color{red}5} & \\
(3, 0)_{\color{red}6} & (2, 1)_{\color{red}7} & (1, 2)_{\color{red}8} & (0, 3)_{\color{red}9} & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}$$

Notice that in each row $x + y$ doesn't change.  So if you want the value for $(x, y)$,

- first add up $1 + 2 + \cdots + (x + y)$, which is a simple arithmetic series, it is $\frac12 (x+y)(x + y + 1)$.
- second add the column value, which is just $x$

So you get simply $\frac{(x + y - 1)(x + y - 1 + 1)}{2} + x$.